# Proof that for all positive reals $a, b$ , if $a <b$, then $n^a$ is little of oh $n^b$.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

For all positive real numbers $a$ and $b$, and $a < b$, then $n^a$ is little oh of $n^b$.
The tricky part of this proof is that for all positive constant $c$, $c(n^b) \geq n^a$ for all $n > n_0$. What would $n_0$ and $c$ be in this case to prove the question? Thanks

Comment: I have to do this prove only using the formal definition of big-oh and little-oh.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition $f(x)=o(g(x)) \iff \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0.$

So if $a<b$ we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^a}{n^b}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{b-a}}=0.$$ Thus $n^a=o(n^b)$ whenever $a<b$.

Since $n^b$ is nonzero for all $b>0$ and all $n>0$, my definition is equivalent. Observe that if for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N$ such that when $n\ge N$ we have $$n^a<\varepsilon n^b\iff \forall\varepsilon>0~\exists N~s.t.~\forall n\ge N, ~\frac{n^a}{n^b}<\varepsilon \iff \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^a}{n^b}=0.$$

Comment: I have to do this prove only using the formal definition of big-oh and little-oh

Comment: Depending upon your source, this is a formal definition. Which definition are you using?